# Play customized Security Controller validation by annotation doesn`t work

Tags: playframework

i have the following customized security controller using the *secure module* for play:

```
public class Security extends Secure.Security {

    static boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {

        validation.required(username);
        validation.required(password);

        if (!validation.hasErrors()) {
            BetaUser user = BetaUser.find("username", username).first();

            if (user != null && user.password.equals(password)) {
                Session.current().put("userid", user.id);
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    static void onAuthenticated() {
        Series.userSeries();
    }

    static void onDisconnected() {
        Application.index();
    }

    static boolean check(String profile) {
        if ("admin".equals(profile)) {
            return Security.connected().equals("admin");
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

In this case the validation mechanism in the *authenticate* methode works. When i use annotations the *password* parameter doesn`t get validatet anymore:

```
static boolean authenticate(@Required String username, @Required String password) {

    if (!validation.hasErrors()) {
        BetaUser user = BetaUser.find("username", username).first();

        if (user != null && user.password.equals(password)) {
            Session.current().put("userid", user.id);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The strange thing is, that the username validation actually does work (error when username is empty). When only the password is left empty the validation has no errors...

I hope that you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I dig around,

### Validating HTTP data with play

> Validations ensure that the data has certain values or meet specific
>   requirements. **You can use validation to verify that your models are
>   correct before saving them to the database**, **or use them directly on
>   HTTP parameters to validate a simple form**.

Ref : http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/validation

Before call your implement method, it call authenticate method in Secure class first. So, this it why annotation it not works in your implement method.

```
public static void authenticate(@Required String username, String password, boolean remember) throws Throwable {
        // Check tokens
        Boolean allowed = false;
        try {
            // This is the deprecated method name
            allowed = (Boolean)Security.invoke("authentify", username, password);
        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e ) {
            // This is the official method name
            allowed = (Boolean)Security.invoke("authenticate", username, password);
        }
        if(validation.hasErrors() || !allowed) {
            flash.keep("url");
            flash.error("secure.error");
            params.flash();
            login();
        }
        // Mark user as connected
        session.put("username", username);
        // Remember if needed
        if(remember) {
            response.setCookie("rememberme", Crypto.sign(username) + "-" + username, "30d");
        }
        // Redirect to the original URL (or /)
        redirectToOriginalURL();
    }
```

Your can see this thread for deep reason why it not works -> [parameter validation with net.sf.oval (in play framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562353/parameter-validation-with-net-sf-oval-in-play-framework)